Strict-origin-when-cross-origin
I have a WordPress website with multilingual (Polylan WP plugin). And these are on separate subdomain. eg.
https://de.main_domain.nl/ and https://en.main_domain.nl/.
https://de.main_domain.nl/ is default site (Primary language). I pointed https://en.main_domain.nl/ same as https://de.main_domain.nl/. And site is working fine. But, there are showing “strict-origin-when-cross-origin” with 403 when I try to submit a ajax form from https://en.main_domain.nl/.
Note: I am trying submit form from https://en.main_domain.nl/ .
Request URL:
https://de.main_domain.nl/?wjbp-ajax=wp_job_board_pro_ajax_apply_email
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
https://i.sstatic.net/Zu64b.png
